# Confusions about the input shape in LSTM models

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I am trying to build a LSTM model which uses the time-series data of currency exchange rate, and the sentiment score of the same date range, to predict the next day exchange rate. Now I have the x_train date which is a pandas data frame [The first column is the rate and second column is the score](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSRrB.png). The y_train data is just the data with only the exchange rate and shifted by one day. The data is from 2016-01-01 to 2017-07-06.

So the X_train has the shape (486,2) and y_train has the shape (486,). I followed some tutorials to reshape X_train to (486,1,2), the input shape is (1,2), batch size is 200 and epoch is 1000. I have a little confusion here.

Does this mean that in each epoch, the model will start from index 1 and take the data of shape (200,1,2) into LSTM to train until the index 286? Or the batch is just selected randomly? How can I make sure that the current batch is related to the next one?

Another question is about the number of units which is another parameters. I set it to four, I think it is the output of each timestep and the input to the next dense layer which will have an output of size 1, is this correct? So this is about the predicting process, right?

Answer (score 0):

If the ***total*** amount of training data you have is 486 time-series points, you'll probably want to get more data. That being said, how time series prediction is usually done is you choose a window size that is smaller than your dataset and say "if I put in the last N days of data in this RNN, can it predict the N+1-th day". Then you iterate over your entire time series selecting N-sized chucks of time series for `X` and setting the N+1-th as your desired prediction (`y`).

**Example**:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf

# fake data.
cny = 8.0 * np.abs(np.random.normal(size=486))
compound = np.random.normal(0, 0.1, size=486)

# make a pandas data-frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'cny': cny, 'compound': compound})

# shift `cny` by one into the future and set that as the label
df['next_cny'] = df['cny'].shift(-1)

# drop the nan that shifting creates
df = df.dropna()

# check the data
print(df.head())

#          cny  compound   next_cny
# 0  10.827493 -0.127950   0.923700
# 1   0.923700  0.039958  12.787946
# 2  12.787946  0.024724  15.817607
# 3  15.817607 -0.065448   5.866374
# 4   5.866374  0.143691   8.864016

# choose a window
window = 16  # <= you can make this whatever you want
num_windows = len(df) - window + 1

# make slices of data
Xs, ys = [], []

for w in range(num_windows):
    current_slice = df.iloc[w:w+window]
    X = current_slice[['cny', 'compound']].values
    y = current_slice['next_cny'].values[-1]
    Xs.append(X)
    ys.append(y)

X = np.stack(Xs)
y = np.stack(ys)

# check the shape
print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)

# (470, 16, 2)
# (470,)

# make a network
x_in = tf.keras.Input([16, 2])
x, *_ = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, return_state=True)(x_in)
x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)(x)

# create model
model = tf.keras.Model(x_in, x_out)

# load data into tensorflow
ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
ds = ds.shuffle(1 << 6).batch(32)

# compile the model
model.compile(optimizer='Adam', loss=tf.keras.losses.MSE)

# train
model.fit(ds, epochs=10)

# Epoch 1/10
# 15/15 [==============================] - 2s 12ms/step - loss: 40.0351
# Epoch 2/10
# 15/15 [==============================] - 0s 10ms/step - loss: 21.3910
# ...
```

One thing to be mindful of when predicting time-series data is that, because of the ordered nature of the data, a model can learn patterns from future data, and use them to forecast the past. Here is a nice post on [cross validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14099/using-k-fold-cross-validation-for-time-series-model-selection) that explains how to split time-series data into train/test sets. Here is a [time-series splitter](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit.html#sklearn.model_selection.TimeSeriesSplit) in scikit-learn.

Comment: Thanks for your answering. I have question about the batch. So in your code, the batch size is 32, and we have 486-16+1 windows. For batch one, I know it will take in the data from window 1 to window 32. But for batch two, will it take the data from window 33 to window 64 or from window 2 to window 33? This is what I don't quite understand.

Comment: The time (2nd dimension) in all the samples (in this example) are of length 16. I looped through the data and grabbed chunks of time series that are length 16, making the 17th value, the label (we're predicting tomorrows value). Then I randomly grabbed 32 of these for a batch. This is how you get the shape `(32, 16, 2)` for your features.

Comment: You said you randomly grabbed 32 of those chunks for a batch, so it is not like what I was saying the chunks were grabbed in a sequence (The first chunk to the 32nd chunk and so on)? Then for one epoch, how should each epoch terminate? After all those chunks were grabbed?

Comment: If we set (shuffle = false), then how would those chunks be selected? Does this make the LSTM  stateful? And which one (Stateless or Stateful) in this case is better?